# Saving in Matlab in txt format and names changing in a loop

Tags: matlab

I need to save in Matlab some matrices in .txt format without commas and with names changing inside a loop, e.g.

```
for h=1:n
A=[1 2 3;
   4 5 6];

%save A as A`h' in .txt format

end
```

without exponential notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fname=sprintf('A%d.txt',h);
dlmwrite(fname,A);
```

or

```
dlmwrite(fname,A,' ');
```

if you want blanks instead of commas

Comment: you can user any delimiter you want, it's the optional 3rd argument of dlmwrite which can be known by typing `help dlmwrite`. I edited the answer to use blanks instead of commas

Answer (score 0):

Use `dlmwrite`. With `precision` you can select how a number is represented as a string and with `delimiter` you can use a tab or space to separate the numbers.

Comment: Can you please write a line of code? I'm not able to change the name in the loop and to avoid commas.

Comment: I have tried save(sprintf('A%d.txt',h), 'A', ascii), but it does not like ascii